# Is arraylist can be used to expose functionality of web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

My application is developed to expose functionality of web service method as Array List. Is there any complications may come while non-dotnet client consume it as Arraylist store anything in object form only. Also if I use generic list instead of arraylist to expose functionality, whether it improve performance of my web service.

Comment: All that the clients would understand is Json or Xml.

Comment: Yes, but as ado.net dataset has some issues with interoperability is same can be with arraylist or generic list

Comment: Say, a plain javascript/html client will not understand what an ArrayList/List/FooList is! Your webservice will have to return the data as an xml or json object. And by generic list are you referring to Generics like List<T>?If that is the case, you cannot compare them wrt performance.

Comment: In wsdl generic list objects are represented by complex type and inside this complex type individual properties are represented as elements with primitive data type i.e. int, string etc., but in arraylist this elements are represented by "anytype" which is due to arraylist store data in object form and so while doing serialization to xml it doesn't understand correct datatype of object.

Comment: @TJ- you're mistaken. Any complex type gets serialized as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with `ArrayList` is that it is an obsolete type, and should not be used for new development. Use a generic list instead.

Your clients will not need to understand the generic list, because they will never see it. Remember that web services *never* expose .NET types - they expose XML. The clients will see a repeating sequence of XML elements with integer content. If you returned `List<int>`, then they would see a sequence of integers. If you returned `List<complexType>`, then they would see a sequence of XML elements with complex content.